# No network capability

Tags: settings, updates, wifi, networking

Just downloaded the most recent update today. After restart, I have no networking capability whatsoever. No wifi, no wired, nothing. Opening networking through settings gives me an error message to the effect of "your network settings aren't compatible with this build " (can't remember the exact wording. Without any internet, I can't download any updates or try to undo the last one. If it matters, I'm using a Lenovo yoga laptop. Help!!!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Updated this morning. Shut down after the update, went to turn it on and the network is lost. When I go to the Settings page for Network I get an error message saying the following: The system network services are not compatible with this version.

Comment: Same issue! Internet is not working!

Comment: Got the same issue. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet

Comment: Sorry for mistakenly commenting as an answer as this is my first time on StackExchange. Pavel Janicek's answer solved the issue. All I needed to do was to download **libnl libnl-genl libnl-route** from another computer that has access to the internet and **sudo dpkg -i libnl-*.deb** the *.deb files. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is most visited question regarding this topic on Elementary OS, I have solution for you

[There is solution described on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/727462/141980)

To cite the answer:

This is caused by a regression introduced with a fix for [libnl3 bug #1511735](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnl3/+bug/1511735).
Resulting network-manager crash has been reported in [network-manager bug #1539513](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539513) or [network-manager bug #1539634](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539634)

and you need to downgrade these packages

The first link helped me, hope it will help you too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and downgrading the `libnl` packages worked too.

I rebooted using a live USB , downloaded `libnl-3-200-3.2.21-1_amd64.deb`, `libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` and `libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/ , installed it using `dpkg -i` and rebooted.

Internet should be working now.